# Given A ⊆ B prove or disprove {x ∈ C : x ∉ B} ⊆ {x ∈ C : x ∉ A}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck on this problem I believe it would be true because all the elements in C are in neither A nor B

Comment: Why would it be true that all the elements  in $C$ are in neither $A$ and $B$?  If you believe this statement is true, you would have to prove it for *any* $A$, $B$, and $C$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the definition of the subset relation. Assuming that some $x$ is a member of the first set, show that it is a member of the second set.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \notin B$ then $x \notin A$ since $A \subseteq B$. If $x \in C$ then $x \in C$. Thus, if $x \in C$ and $x \notin B$ then $x \in C$ and $x \notin A$. In other words $(C \setminus B) \subseteq (C \setminus A)$.

Answer (score 0):

you have  $x\in B^c \Rightarrow x \in A^c $
 and you don't really have to care about the $C$ since you are looking at :

$C\cap A^c $ and $C \cap B^c$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $A\subseteq B$, then $B^c\subseteq A^c$.